# Error when trying to open a text file using Process.Start in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I'm working on a console application in C# using .NET 6.0. I have a Journal class that stores entries and a Persistence class to save the journal entries to a file. I'm encountering an error when I try to open the saved text file using `Process.Start`. The error message is as follows:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (193): An error occurred trying to start process 'c:\temp\journal.txt' with working directory 'C:\Mentorship\Design Patterns\bin\Debug\net6.0'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

relevant part of my code:

```cs
var p = new Persistence();
var filename = @"c:\temp\journal.txt";
p.SaveToFile(j, filename);
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(filename));
```

I'm expecting this code to open the saved text file using the default associated program. However, I'm getting the error mentioned above. How can I resolve this issue and successfully open the text file using `Process.Start` in .NET 6.0?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me (after adding a closing `}` to the `Journal` class). You state, *"i am expecting to write a file to a disk without any error"*, yet the error doesn't appear to have anything to do with writing a file, but rather opening a file. Based on the error message, you might need to specify `UseShellExecute = true`, as the problem appears to be that it's not using the default editor for text files to open the file: `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = filename, UseShellExecute = true } )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the exception message tells you in plain text:

> An error occurred trying to start process 'c:\temp\journal.txt' with working directory 'C:\Mentorship\Design Patterns\bin\Debug\net6.0'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

So, your program tried to execute the journal.txt file like it was a program. This correlates with this code line in your code: `Process.Start(filename)`.

Note that this is not a problem with writing the text file as you seem to assume. The problem lies chiefly with trying to **execute** the written text file like a program.

If your desire is to open the text file in a text editor, then `Process.Start(string)` won't help, as it does not work with non-executable files. (It did in the past, but the behavior of *Process.Start(string)* [had been changed with .NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/fx-core#change-in-default-value-of-useshellexecute).) To tell the OS to open the text file with the associated application (typically a text editor), you can use the `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` method together with explicitly setting [`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-useshellexecute) to *true*:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(txtFilePath)
{
    UseShellExecute = true
};

Process.Start(psi);
```

---

In typical Microsoft fashion, the .NET team did not manage to update the official API documentation for `Process.Start(string)` reflecting the changed behavior since it was introduced with .NET Core 2.1 in 2018. While there has been a bug report filed regarding the outdated documentation (https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/8727), the documentation issue still persists to this day... :-(

Comment: For what it's worth, the documentation for [`UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) does mention this, but there's no way a beginner would know to look there for that information when all they want is to start a process.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, yes, a reader of the Process.Start(string) documentation has no reason to suspect there is anything foul with the documentation and to look elsewhere for something that seems unrelated to Process.Start(string), especially if they are a beginner not yet very familiar with the .NET eco-system.